# sphinx: custom image directive surrounded by unwanted html link

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'd like to use a custom image directive "Autoimage" which allows for different scaling options for different builders in Sphinx v1.0.8. The scaling works, but for reasons unknown to me the html output gets surrounded by an `<a href=...>` tag. Example:

```
.. image:: /img/foo.png
```

results in

```
<img src="../_images/foo.png" alt="foo"></img>
```

whereas

```
.. autoimage:: /img/foo.png
```

results in

```
<a class="reference internal" href="../_images/foo.png">
    <img style="width: 16.0px; height: 16.0px;" src="../_images/foo.png" alt="foo"></img>
</a>
```

Here is my autoimage implementation, which is a subclass of the internal Image directive:

```
import os
from docutils import nodes
from docutils.parsers.rst import directives
from docutils.parsers.rst.directives.images import Image


class Autoimage(Image):
    option_spec = {
            'scale-html': directives.percentage,
            'scale-latex': directives.percentage,
            'scale-epub2': directives.percentage,
            'scale-mobi': directives.percentage,
            'scale': directives.percentage,
            }

    def run(self):
        env = self.state.document.settings.env
        builder_name = env.app.builder.name

        # treat all filenames as relative to the source dir (of the project)
        if self.arguments[0].startswith('/') or self.arguments[0].startswith(os.sep):
            relFileBase = self.arguments[0][1:]
        else:
            relFileBase = self.arguments[0]

        extension = ''
        defaultScale = 100
        # when using LaTeX, look for pdf images first
        if builder_name == 'latex':
            defaultScale = 50
            extension = '.pdf'
        # use png images as the default/fallback
        realPath = os.path.join(env.srcdir, relFileBase + extension)
        if extension == '' or not os.path.exists(realPath):
            extension = '.png'

        realPath = os.path.join(env.srcdir, relFileBase + extension)
        if not os.path.exists(realPath):
            print('Could not find image %s' % realPath)
            return False

        self.arguments[0] = self.arguments[0] + extension

        # this gets cached in the environment and is shared among builds,
        # so for this to work use -E with sphinx-build :/
        self.options['scale'] = self.options.get('scale-' + builder_name, defaultScale)

        return Image.run(self)


def setup(app):
    app.add_directive('autoimage', Autoimage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx automatically adds a link to the original version whenever the "scale" option is used, even if the scale is 100%.